# Stop path processing

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap, cypher, spatial

I am new in neo4j and trying to understand how can I optimize routing queries.

I am working with OSM db.

and I am trying to calclulate the distance from one point to another.

```
START a=node(760119) 
MATCH path=(a)-[:NEXT|NODE*1..30]-(c) 
WHERE HAS(c.node_osm_id) AND c.node_osm_id=283103898 
RETURN DISTINCT reduce( 
    distance = 0, n in filter(
        x in path where has(x.length)
    ) | distance + n.length
) AS distance order by distance
```

My query returns a set of distances.

```
319.5609607071325
320.0901127819706
321.64043860878735
332.13372820085
334.21320610250484
```

How can i rewrite the query, to stop looking for new paths if the distance is longer than the shortest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher doesn't have support for shortest path with cost evaluation yet (as of 2.0-RC1). If you need to use a more efficient shortest path algorithm, you'll need to implement an unmanaged extension.

However, I do see where you might be able to improve your performance... have you tried adding C as a start point query?

Comment: What about embedded algorithms like dijkstra? Its available though REST API. Is it possible to use it with two different types of relation (NODE and NEXT in my case) and where only one of them has weight?

Comment: Yes, dijkstra is what you would use. I think you may end up needing a custom unmanaged extension--don't see a way to specify both relationship types in the REST API.